# SQL: Check for duplicates in 2 columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm building a web application where users can answer questions. I'm trying to run a query where these answers are inserted in a table but where a user can only   reply once the same question. In my case the query must check on duplicates at question_id & reply_user. (reply_id is already defined as the primary key).

For example when I have in my table answers : question_id = 1 & reply_user = John, John cannot reply anymore on question_id 1. But another user can of course.

I'm currently running this:

```
INSERT INTO replies (question_id, reply_user, reply_content, reply_anwer)
  VALUES (:questionid, :replyuser, :replycontent, :replyanswer)
  SELECT question_id, reply_user FROM replies WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT question_id FROM replies
      WHERE question_id = question_id AND reply_user = reply_user
  )
```

I tried out with WHERE NOT EXISTS but I couldn't find a solution with that.

Thank's for your help

Comment: Add a unique index that contains both fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `unique` 2 filed:

```
ALTER TABLE `replies` ADD UNIQUE (`question_id`,`reply_user`);
```

And then use this query:

```
INSERT INTO replies (question_id, reply_user, reply_content, reply_anwer)
VALUES (:questionid, :replyuser, :replycontent, :replyanswer)
```

IF `question_id` , `reply_user` exist query not run else run.

Answer (score 0):

create a index unique on the two keys

```
ALTER TABLE replies ADD UNIQUE `preventDoubleAnswer` (`question_id`, `reply_user`) COMMENT '';
```

and insert the data as:

```
INSERT IGNORE ...
```

The `INSERT IGNORE` will insert a new data only if the unique key is satisfied.
NB: is the `IGNORE` param is omitted, it will throw a MYSQL error